# Front Porch Posts Not Contacting Porch Slab

Tags: load-bearing, post, porch

After removing my front porch railing, I noticed that 3 of the 4 porch posts do not make full contact with the porch slab. The one closest to the front door is the one that doesn't move around. The others move around quite a bit on the bottom.
I don't remember the posts moving around before I removed the railing.

Are these load bearing?

Is there danger of the porch collapsing?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If they are not load bearing (hopefully an expert can tell you from your attic photos) they still  shouldn't be dangling loosely from the rafters.  Your railing should have some strength, hopefully enough that someone can sit on it.  Put some L brackets at the bottom or drive wedges between the tops and the roof (then you can put some trim over it).

Comment: I took the railing down, and don't plan to put a new one up. Wanted to open the porch up. I have sat on the railing before with no issue. I thought about putting a shim under them so they wouldn't move around.

Comment: I like what you did.  If I may say so, for an open look remove the two center posts that are obscuring the shutters and just shim up the corner one if it needs it.  You could probably just put quarters under those little metal feet. :)

Comment: I like your thinking. That will be my next step as long as they aren't load bearing! That'd really open things up. Good idea about the quarters.

Answer (score 1):

Typically in cases like this you'll have cantilevered trusses in the roof system with an interior bearing point. The posts are entirely decorative (and hold the railing system). The biggest clue is the shape of the gable.

It's possible that only the one by the door is carrying a load. There could be a small beam there for the high front gable, but that's not likely. You'll need to peek into your attic to be sure, but considering the design and apparent age of the home it's a safe bet.

Comment: Thank you for the info. The home was built in 1996 for reference. What should I be looking for in the attic? Perhaps I could take a photo and post here for further insight.

Comment: If the insulation isn't obscuring things you'll see paper markers fastened at the gussets indicating bearing points. Mostly it's the general truss design we're after.

Comment: I added photos to the original question. Maybe that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Those vertical webs would seem to indicate a bearing point, but you don't show the tags I  mentioned. You'd have to move some insulation or look behind the cardboard barriers.

Comment: I went back up and moved some installation around but didn't see the markers. I looked around at all the gussets I could see in the attic and didn't see any.

Comment: I think your main roof load is carried by the vertical legs (in the second picture from the last) down to the (hidden) beam below. The outer edge carries very little if the hidden beam is stiff. I'll keep an eye on the movement of the posts after snow events.